# Kotlin: Passing the implementation of an interface as parameter

Tags: kotlin

I'm very new to Kotlin.
Can someone help me how to pass the implementation as a parameter in Kotlin?

I have this interface

```
interface MyInterface {
}
```

And I have two classes that implements that interface like this:

First Class:

```
class MyFirstClass : MyInterface {
}
```

Second Class:

```
class MySecondClass : MyInterface {
}
```

Now I have a method that needs `MyInterface` as parameter like this

```
fun someMethod(param: MyInterface) {
}
```

And when I call that method like this:

```
somethod(MySecondClass())
```

I got a compilation error that I need `MyInterface` as a parameter

But in java, it's ok

Comment: are you sure that the parameter type of `MyInterface`  is your defined `MyInterface`? maybe you imported another same name interface. :)

Comment: I try to reproduce it, but is impossible

Comment: Oh man! I'm embarrass right now. You're right @holi-java.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for this question.
Like @holi-java said, I imported another package with same name interface

Comment: Unfortunately, SO doesn't allow me to delete this question stating that `others have invested time and effort into answering it` :/

Comment: ah ok - thanks for trying anyway!